# Dependency is not satisfiable: libgtk2-perl

Tags: apt, perl

I am trying to install gmusicbrowser in ubuntu 22.04 but sadly I am getting the below errors.

I have `sudo apt install libglib2.0-dev` in a blind hope it might install perl, but no such luck.

```
sudo gdebi /mnt/nas/Downloads/gmusicbrowser_1.1.16_all.deb
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Reading state information... Done
This package is uninstallable
Dependency is not satisfiable: libgtk2-perl
```

Comment: GTK2 is *deprecated*, with GTK3 in *maintenance* mode & GTK4 the *development* & *stable* release of GTK libs. The deprecated `libgtk2-perl` is last available in *focal* or 20.04 (https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/libgtk2-perl)

Comment: This software looks unmaintained for several years.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The GTK2 framework is deprecated and should not be used.

Because of this, the `libgtk2-perl` source package which is NOT part of core GTK libraries was removed at the request of its own maintainer in [Debian Bug #986109](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=986109), with effective removal in October 2021.  As such, it was removed from Ubuntu between 20.04 and 22.04.  **It is not available, and should not be relied on because it is an unmaintained package.**

Additionally, the `gmusicbrowser` package was removed from Debian because it has been **unmaintained for years** (see [Debian Bug #942001 about the removal](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=942001)) and in turn was ALSO removed from Ubuntu in August of 2019 as well for the same reason (see the Debian bug).

**I would advise against using `gmusicbrowser`** as it is unmaintained, buggy, and uses deprecated **and unmaintained** scripts that were removed for those reasons.  You may want to find an alternative software instead.

Comment: Dam... this is like a shot to my heart!!! First winamp, which was customisable and hotkeyed to hell. But now the only good music player.... ahhh I bleed!!! lol I bleed!!! Thank you for this. I will find a way to get it running, or possible just stay on 20.04 :P

Comment: @JamieHutber note 20.04 goes end of standard support and becomes offtopic here next year, so you can't stay on 20.04 forever if you want continued support :)

Comment: Heh, ye I wouldn't really downgrade, even if I wanted to work would not allow it. Turns out Gmusic has a version that runs on gtk3, but its not a deb https://gmusicbrowser.org/devel.html So its saved me